# How to call one command from another in package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json

suppose if i have some script in package.json like this

```
 "scripts": {
    "a1": "first command",
    "a2": "second command",
    "a3": "third command",
      
  }
```

and if i want to run script **a1** and **a2** in the script **a3** how can i do this? can this be possible? I am using

> node version : v6.9.4
>
> npm version : 4.3.0

i want to achieve something like this

```
"scripts": {
    "a1": "first command",
    "a2": "second command",
    "a3": "third command && a1 && a2",
      
  }
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `npm run` inside the script. E.g.

```json
"scripts": {
  "a1": "first command",
  "a2": "second command",
  "a3": "third command && npm run a1 && npm run a2",
}
```

Running `$ npm run a3` via the CLI will run the `third command` (whatever that is), followed by `a1`, then `a2`.

However, if running `$npm run a3` via the CLI is to only run `a1` followed by `a2` then:

```json
"scripts": {
  "a1": "first command",
  "a2": "second command",
  "a3": "npm run a1 && npm run a2",
}
```

Comment: When I run `npm run a3`, the exit code is always 0 even if a1 or a2 fails with a non-zero exit  code.

Answer (score -1):

you can run one script from to another script is just mention a target command into source command script.

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "npm run format && npm run lint &&  vite",
"build": "npm run format && npm run lint && tsc && vite build",
"lint": "eslint . --fix --max-warnings=0",
"format": "prettier . --write",
"preview": "vite preview",
"lint-staged": "lint-staged --config lint-staged.js",
"husky-install": "husky install"
```

}