# what is this rimraf argument --tsconfig about

Tags: node.js, scripting, package.json, npm-scripts

I'm new to Node and In this *package.json* for React Typescript project I understand what `rimraf` does but what is the `--tsconfig` doing at the end?

When I run  the `prebuild` script I see that the file *typedoc.json* is deleted. But why this `--tsconfig`? There is a *tsconfig.json* file but I can’t see that `rimraf` is doing anything

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsdx build --transpileOnly --entry ./src/index.js",
    "prebuild": "npm run docs",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "docs": "rimraf typedoc.json && typedoc --tsconfig",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
},
```

The source for this code is [notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack/blob/master/package.json) package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `rimraf` will not do anything to the `tsconfig.json` file. It’s important to understand that the `docs` script in the *package.json* file, i.e. this part;

```json
"docs": "rimraf typedoc.json && typedoc --tsconfig",
```

consists of two separate commands and together they are referred to as a *"compound command"*.

The `typedoc --tsconfig` part is the second command and it’s not part of the `rimraf` command because it’s on the right-hand side of the [`&&`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) operator. The `--tsconfig` part is actually an argument for the `typedoc` command (...it *is not* an argument for the `rimraf` command).

Essentially the `typedoc` command and its associated `--tsconfig` argument, that is on the right-hand side of the `&&` operator, is only invoked if the command on the left-hand side of it, (i.e. the first command `rimraf typedoc.json`),  completes successfully with a zero exit code.

The [`typedoc`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc) command is what generates documentation  for TypeScript projects.

The `--tsconfig` argument for thé `typedoc` command is described as follows in the [documentation](https://github.com/TypeStrong/TypeDoc#arguments)

> `--tsconfig <path/to/tsconfig.json>`
>
> Specify a typescript config file that should be loaded. If not specified TypeDoc will look for 'tsconfig.json' in the current directory.

Note: In your usage of the `--tsconfig` argument it doesn’t specify a custom filepath to the `tsconfig.json` file, therefore it utilizes the one in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks, how does "prebuild": "npm run docs",`` to run doc and not to run some doc.script file

Comment: That's because the `prebuild` script starts with the [npm-run-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script) command. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978355/how-to-call-one-command-from-another-in-package-json/42978578#42978578) that describes how to call one command from another in _package.json_ - it should help you better understand.