# How to run server only after webpack completes bundling bundles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
```

how to run `npm run build` first and then `npm start` in a single command?

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start-dev" : "npm run build && npm run start"
   },
```

I tried the command `npm run start-dev`. But only webpack is being compiled. The server isn't running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call one command from another in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978355/how-to-call-one-command-from-another-in-package-json)

Comment: yes,it is similar. but the second command is not being executed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that doesn't work, but, anyway, you can try this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start-dev" : "webpack && node server.js"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      npm i npm-run-all
```

this package never run into issue. You can add as many as commands

```
   "dev:start": "npm-run-all build start",
```