# Run NestJs command from another command

Tags: nestjs

I want to create a NestJS command that would execute different NestJS commands (migration launcher) by theirs command names.
So, basically I have a command with name:

```
command: 'migrations:run',
```

And I need it to run a different command, for example:

```
command: 'migration:some-schema-update:up',
```

Any ideas? Can't find this in the documentation.
https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/nest-commander

Comment: isn't this something similar that you want? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42978578

Comment: What do you mean by "NestJS" commands? Nest is a framework for NodeJS. It has its own CLI with commands like `build`, `start`, `generate`, etc, but it looks like you're talking about scripts in your `package.json`

Comment: Check out the documentation link I left in the question